# Set Share Permissions of all folders in a share based on Security Permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, share, user-permissions

So this might be a little complicated.... I have created a script which generates lists of all the people that have Security permissions on a share. The issue is that the share permission to a share will be different than the security permissions. I want to remove all share permissions and set the share permissions to the same people with the same full control as the security permissions.

I need to run this on four different servers so I need a script that will change that. Any ideas or resources?

---

**Edit:** After discussion with my colleagues the objective has slightly changed. Now I want to use `Set-Acl` to basically remove full control from all users EXCEPT one specific group. This shouldn't be too difficult right? I would simply throw a for each share - for each user- if user not in specific group then set acl to remove full control.

How does one remove permissions? I see commands for setting FC but not for removing.

Comment: Set share permissions to `Everyone:FullControl` and do access control with just the filesystem permissions. They allow more fine-grained control anyway. If anything, enable access-based enumeration on the shares, so that people see only the files/folders they actually have access to.

Comment: There are some major bugs with get-acl and set-acl that are still present in later versions of PowerShell, but this is possible. I'll try and get to a reply later tonight!

Comment: Hi @RichardDakin so after discussion with my colleagues the objective has slightly changed. Now I want to use set-acl to basically remove full control from all users EXCEPT one specific group. This shouldn't be too difficult right? I would simply throw a for each share - for each user- if user not in specific group then set acl  to remove full control.... how does one remove permissions? I see commands for setting FC but not for removing.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove full control from all users except one group"? Do you want to entirely remove access for all those users? Just for the ones with full access? Remove just full access (if so, what permissions should remain)?

Answer (score 0):

As per your reply, this way removes all the bugs from GET-ACL and SET-ACL so can be used in earlier versions of PowerShell. Once it's removed, you can change this (reference $PERM) to add back on the group you want to retain access. Let me know if you need it tweaking.

```
 $folderpath = "Somefolderpath"

 write-Output "Removing inheritance " 
 $acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
 $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
 $acl | Set-Acl
 $acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
 $acl.Access |where {$_.IdentityReference -eq "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated 
 Users"} |%{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
 $acl | Set-Acl

If ($?){
Write-Output "Inheritance Removed"
} 
write-Output "Set permissions" 
$acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
$perm = "AddGroupHere","FullControl","Allow"
$accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule 
$perm
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl

If ($?){
 Write-Output "ACL set"
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have never written PS before. If I want to perform this for every folder within a share how would i wrap that in a foreach ?

Comment: [cmdletbinding()]

param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]$Computer = '.') 

$shares = gwmi -Class win32_share -ComputerName $computer | select -ExpandProperty Name 

foreach ($share in $shares) { 
  try{ 
  
  $share1="SERVER PATH" + $share
  if(Test-Path  $share1)
  #write-host $share1
 {
  write-output $share
   get-acl $share1 | %{ $_.Access  } |  ft -property IdentityReference, AccessControlType, FileSystemRights
   }
   else
   {
   throw  $share 
   }
   }

catch
{
 write-output "STRING HERE "
}

Comment: Sorry for lack of formatting- this is what i am currently using for gathering names of all logins on each share. I removed the SERVERPATH And STRING HERE for security.

Comment: Attempted to use on just one test folder Getting Two errors "new-object : a constructor was not found. cannot find an appropriate constructor for type"

Comment: Other error: Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null"